# how to create a test for selenium in C# using visual studio

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2013, ui-automation, pageobjects

i have little experience on eclipse to do test automation using selenium in java,here i used page object pattern.

now i want implement page factory-page object pattern in C# in visual studio for selenium ,this is the first time am going to use visual studio,so struggling to create new project,packages and  classes under each package....

i observed while creating a new project in VS,there are many application under visual C# -->Windows Desktop-->here which one i can select?
Application are:Windows Forms Application,WPF,Class Library,..

and saw one more place to create Unit Test Project under Visual C#-->Test-->

which one i need to choose to create N unit test for selenium ?Under Test? or Under Windows Desktop?

In java, i can create different packages and different classes to design my framework, but where as in C# i don't see packages concept ,here i know we can use namespace.

my requirement is :

1. pkg1-->put all common classes with common methods
2. pkg2-->put all common GUI classes
3. pkg3-->put all results classes
4. pkg4->put all page factory classes
5. pkg5-->put all interfaces,abstract classes
6. pkg6-->put all related to maven and other classes

is it possible to design this way in C# using VS-2013?

please help me to design a framework in C#.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, namespace in C# like package in Java.
In Visual Studio, you can create new folder under project and all of class under this folder will have same namespace.